# Riemann Zeta representation when $\operatorname{Re}(s)<0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, riemann-zeta

I am looking for series representation of Riemann Zeta function for $\operatorname{Re}(s)<0$ or  $\operatorname{Re}(s)>-3$ or $\operatorname{Re}(s)>-4$ whatever is simplier.

Maybe something like from this wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Riemann's_functional_equation) or equation 20 from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html) which works only for $\operatorname{Re}(s)>0$.

$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}$$

**UPDATE 1 (04/11/2019)**

Finally, I had some time to check it.

I tried this, based on the answer from reuns, when $\Re(s) > -k$:
$$\zeta(s) = \frac{\eta(s)}{1-2^{1-s}} = \frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}} \Big( \sum_{j=1}^{k+1} 2^{-j} f_{j-1}(1,s)+ 2^{-k-1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} f_{k+1} (n,s))\Big)$$

and the numerical calculation does not match with the library function. This is a screenshot from Wolfram Mathematica, which I used for numerical check. I tried to calculate the value of $\zeta(s=0.5+15i)$. I put some comments in order to explain it. Also, instead of infinity, I calculated the sum up to 10000, but if I increase it, it returns more or less the same value.

[image]

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Globally_convergent_series) on the same Wiki page

Comment: Probably you want :$$\zeta \left( s \right) ={\frac {{\pi}^{s-1/2}\Gamma \left( 1/2-s/2
 \right) \sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \left( {j}^{1-s} \right) ^{-1}}{\Gamma
 \left( s/2 \right) }}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $$f_0(n,s) = n^{-s}, \qquad f_k(n,s) = f_{k-1}(n,s)-f_{k-1}(n+1,s)= \sum_{m=0}^k {k \choose m} (-1)^m (n+m)^{-s}$$
Using the binomial series $(n+a)^{-s} = n^{-s} \sum_{l=0}^\infty {-s \choose l} (a/n)^l$ show that $f_k(n,s) = O(n^{-s-k})$ and $\partial_s f_k(n,s) = O(n^{-s-k}\log n)$

Note $$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} = \frac{1+(-1)^{n+1}}{2}$$

By induction if for $\Re(s) > 1$ $$\eta(s) = \sum_{j=1}^k 2^{-j}f_{j-1}(1,s) + 2^{-k} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} f_k (n,s)$$
then $$\eta(s) = \sum_{j=1}^k 2^{-j} f_j(1,s) + 2^{-k} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} )( f_k (n,s)- f_k (n+1,s))$$
$$ = \sum_{j=1}^{k+1} 2^{-j} f_{j-1}(1,s)+ 2^{-k-1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} f_{k+1} (n,s)$$
the latter is absolutely convergent and holomorphic thus analytic for $\Re(s) > -k$ thus it is the analytic continuation of $\eta(s) = (1-2^{1-s}) \zeta(s)$

Comment: Looks exactly what I need. I will try to make it myself for R(s)>−3, test numerically and share the results.

Comment: I tried your formulas, but it does not work. Maybe I did not understand it correctly? I put some details in UPDATE 1 in the description of the question. Could you please have a look?